# How to fix Missing Origin Validation error for "webpack-dev-server" in npm

Tags: npm, laravel-5

> npm audit

```
                   === npm audit security report ===


                             Manual Review
         Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve

      Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance
```

High            Missing Origin Validation

Package         webpack-dev-server

Patched in      >=3.1.6

Dependency of   laravel-mix [dev]

Path            laravel-mix > webpack-dev-server

More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/725

found 1 high severity vulnerability in 11710 scanned packages
  1 vulnerability requires manual review. See the full report for details.

How to fix this i cannot use laravel
whenever i try run command "npm run dev" it shows several problem

Answer (score 5):

This audit is just pointing out a vulnerability in your version of the `webpack-dev-server` package.

I don't think it's related to the other problems you're encountering when you run `npm run dev` as I'm currently using a vulnerable version of the same package in my dev environment as well and it works fine.

If you're using laravel mix, it is dependent on a vulnerable version of `webpack-dev-server` (2.11.1) so you can't really fix this problem and will see this annoying audit message until laravel mix is updated to use a newer, secure version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must wait to update laravel-mix.
Ref link: https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1809 
Because version of webpack-dev-server < 3.1.6 in laravel-mix.

Answer (score -3):

Quick solution:

Turning off npm audit on package installation
https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Hahaha disabling security issue is one of the worst suggestion